# Multiplication table with for loop from 1-10

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to create a multiplication table from 1-10, 
but I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIHFe.png) and I'm supposed to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xhY9.png).

What am I doing wrong?

```
let tabel = " "; 

for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++){ 

    console.log(" " + a); 
    tabel = " ";

    for (b = 1; b <= 10; b++) { 

        tabel += " " + (a * b) + " ";  
    }

    console.log(tabel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing wrong many things, for example:

1. You're writing unnecessary logs `console.log(" " + a);` which should not be in your table
2. You're putting spaces between numbers independently of how much symbols your number contains. That's why you get wrong formatting.

As to me, your code should look smth like this:

```js
let tt = ""; 

for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++){ 

    for (b = 1; b <= 10; b++) { 

        const result = String(a * b); // Just converting result of multiplication to a sting
        tt += ' '.repeat(4 - result.length) + result; // Prepending result with appropriate number of spaces
    }
    tt += '\n'; // Adding linewrap (in Windows systems maybe you should use \r\n instead of \n)
}
console.log(tt);
```

Comment: let space = " ";

for (a = 1; a < 11; a++){ 

    table = '\n' 

    for (b = 1; b < 11; b++) { 

        table +=  space + (a * b); 
    }

    console.log(table);
}

Comment: I want to use this code, because I havn't learnt your method, but my table are not in line, do you have any idea for that?

Comment: Because the number of spaces between numbers should be different. Just open the expected result and count the number of spaces between  '1 and 2' and between '90 and 100'

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        let t = j * i; // simply do multiplication first to get next number
        console.log(i + " x " + j + " = " + t); // using t print direct value of multiplication
    }
    console.log("");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate only the result cells, this is simply:

```js
const numDigits = (n) =>
  Math.max(Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n))), 0) + 1; // Number of digits

const multiplicationTable = (n = 10) =>
  ((size) =>
    Array.from({ length: n }, (_, r) =>              // Row index: 0 -> n
      Array.from({ length: n }, (_, c) =>            // Col index: 0 -> n
        `${(r + 1) * (c + 1)}`.padStart(size, ' '))  // Cell value
      .join(' '))                                    // Join columns
    .join('\n'))                                     // Join rows
  (numDigits(n ** 2));                               // Pre-compute pad length

console.log(multiplicationTable(12));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Result:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
  3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36
  4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
  6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
  7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84
  8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96
  9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 108
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120
 11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121 132
 12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144
```

If you want to generate a multiplication table (with formatting), you will need to render `n+1` rows and columns.

```js
const numDigits = (n) =>
  Math.max(Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n))), 0) + 1; // Number of digits

const multiplicationTable = (n = 10) =>
  ((size) =>
    Array.from({ length: n + 1 }, (_, r) =>      // Row index: 0 -> n+1
      Array.from({ length: n + 1 }, (_, c) =>    // Col index: 0 -> n+1
        (r | c) === 0                            // If top-left cell
          ? ''.padStart(size, ' ')               // Top-left cell
          : r === 0                              // If first row
            ? `${c}`.padStart(size, ' ')         // Column header cell
            : c === 0                            // If first column
              ? `${r}`.padStart(size, ' ')       // Row header cell
              : `${r * c}`.padStart(size, ' '))  // Cell value
      .join(' '))                                // Join columns
    .join('\n'))                                 // Join rows
  (numDigits(n ** 2));                           // Pre-compute pad length

console.log(multiplicationTable(12));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Result:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
  1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
  2   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
  3   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36
  4   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
  5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
  6   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
  7   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84
  8   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96
  9   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 108
 10  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120
 11  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121 132
 12  12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144
```

---

### More verbose

A more verbose version for the first example:

```js
function multiplicationTable(n = 10) {
  const padSize = Math.pow(n, 2).toString().length;
  let result = '';
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < n; rowIndex++) {
    let row = '';
    for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < n; colIndex++) {
      let value = (rowIndex + 1) * (colIndex + 1);
      row += value.toString().padStart(padSize, ' ');
      if (colIndex < n) { row += ' '; }
    }
    result += row;
    if (rowIndex < n) { result += '\n'; }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(multiplicationTable(12));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

A more verbose version for the second example:

```js
function multiplicationTable(n = 10) {
  const padSize = Math.pow(n, 2).toString().length;
  let result = '';
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < n + 1; rowIndex++) {
    let row = '';
    for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < n + 1; colIndex++) {
      let value;
      if (rowIndex === 0 && colIndex === 0) {
        value = '';
      } else if (rowIndex === 0) {
        value = colIndex.toString();
      } else if (colIndex === 0) {
        value = rowIndex.toString();
      } else {
        value = (rowIndex * colIndex).toString();
      }
      row += value.padStart(padSize, ' ');
      if (colIndex < n) { row += ' '; }
    }
    result += row;
    if (rowIndex < n) { result += '\n'; }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(multiplicationTable(12));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```